# Index huge data into Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch and have huge data(more than 16k huge rows in the mysql table). I need to push this data into elasticsearch and am facing problems indexing it into it. 
Is there a way to make indexing data faster? How to deal with huge data?

Comment: 16K documents is in fact a small number. Indexing time depends mostly on your index definition (anaylzers used etc.) and Lucene configuration values such as `mergeFactor`. It's hard to give you any precise answer without this information, but you can start with increasing `mergeFactor` to see if the problem is on elasticsearch side. Maybe the bottleneck is somewhere else?

Comment: the code i am using to index is simply `foreach($results as $row){
 $json=json_encode((array)$row);
 $e->add($type,$counter++,$json);
}
function add($type,$id, $data)
        {
                return $this->call($type . '/' . $id, array('method' => 'PUT', 'header' => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n", 'content' => $data));
        }


`
and I guess I have not used any analyzers.And the problem is not with 16k rows but those rows have fields which themselves contain data of entire table. So the amount of data to index is huge.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the `mergeFactor` then? Or profiling how long it takes to `json_encode` these "entire tables"?

Comment: i dont know about mergeFactor...and json_encode is quite fast...so i dont think we have a problem there.

Answer (score 3):

### Expanding on the [Bulk API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html)

You will make a POST request to the `/_bulk`

Your payload will follow the following format where `\n` is the newline character.

```
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
...
```

**Make sure your json is not pretty printed**

The available actions are `index`, `create`, `update` and `delete`.

---

### Bulk Load Example

To answer your question, if you just want to bulk load data into your index.

```
{ "create" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "3" } }
{ "field1" : "value3" }
```

The first line contains the action and metadata.  In this case, we are calling `create`.  We will be inserting a document of type `type1` into the index named `test` with a manually assigned id of `3` (instead of elasticsearch auto-generating one).

The second line contains all the fields in your mapping, which in this example is just `field1` with a value of `value3`.

You will just concatenate as many as these as you'd like to insert into your index.

Comment: Thanks Kirk. Would you mind expanding your example, I would like to work with this further. So using your example, if I have 100 entries from (say) a database to index, I will create a single JSON of 200 lines, right? What would the URL be to post this to the indexing server? Can you provide an example of a full JSON string that does this?

Comment: OK, I found this, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html that will send mw on my way.

Answer (score 2):

This may be an old thread but I though I would comment anyway for anyone who is looking for a solution to this problem. The JDBC river plugin for Elastic Search is very useful for importing data from a wide array of supported DB's.

[Link to JDBC' River source here..](http://goo.gl/69b7LY)
Using Git Bash' curl command I **PUT** the following configuration document to allow for communication between ES instance and MySQL instance -

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/uber/_meta' -d '{
"type" : "jdbc",
"jdbc" : {
 "strategy" : "simple",
 "driver" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
 "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/elastic",
 "user" : "root",
 "password" : "root",
 "sql" : "select * from tbl_indexed",
 "poll" : "24h",
 "max_retries": 3,
 "max_retries_wait" : "10s"
 },
 "index": {
 "index": "uber",
 "type" : "uber",
 "bulk_size" : 100
 }
}'
```

Ensure you have the **mysql-connector-java-VERSION-bin** in the river-jdbc plugin directory which contains jdbc-river' necessary JAR files.

Answer (score 0):

Try bulk api

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/bulk.html

Comment: Please expand on your answer, link-only answers are not future-proof

Comment: Bulk API with curl won't take my multiline json data about 2g in size.